# How can i convert 123456789 to 1.234.567,89 on basis of **Currency Symbol** like Euro(€) etc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin

How can i convert 123456789 to 1.234.567,89 on basis of **Currency Symbol** like Euro(€) etc?
I have 123456789 and i want €1.234.567,89

I have tried using CurrentCulture but it doesn't resolve

Comment: Have you a integer or a string as source? How did you try to convert, may be post some code.

Comment: You don't convert, you format (if the value is of a correct type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.ToString("C")`. Something like this:

```
var cost = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(cost.ToString("C"));
```

That uses the current culture of the system it is running on. So if your regional settings are setup for Euro, it will show as Euro.

To force it to use a specific culture, you can use this (this example uses France, so it shows Euro):

```
cost.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"))
```

More info is here, including how to change the default culture (instead of specifying it each time): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/currency-formatting-in-the-dotnet-framework

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

Gabriel Luci's Answer asume that you (or whoever made the backend DB) tried to get around the issue of [Floating Point imprecision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) by storing the Currency values as a Integer. This is a very reliable and time honored approach. From a Legal reason it might even be nessesary to store 4 digits of precision (even if you are only supposed to display two digits for the normal use purposes, accounting may requires that level of precision).

If the Data is a String/NVARCHAR you would first have to parse it to a intger before Garbiel Lucis Solution works. I would advise using BigInteger as it has no caps on the largest storeable Number. Alterantively you could modify the string via string processing (adding some Commas and Decimal poitns)

You did also mention asp.net in your tags. And Webservers are notorious for having Culture issues. Current Culture uses the Culture of the Computer the Webpage is **running on**. What you need is the culture the Browser is running in.
I am unsure if there is any easy way to get the Browsers side culture. Or if you can somehow get the browser to do that Translation for you (so it uses the culture it runs in).

Answer (score 0):

1. First, the question is unclear of the input being a int, string or other
2. Your question is "How to format a C# string/integer into a given currency string with N decimals"

Let's assume you have the string ("worst" case scenario)

1. You could first transform the string to integer to ease setting up the decimals
2. Manually add your decimals (in this case dividing by "100.0")
3. Format the double value with your number and decimals in place

   - To do so I used "CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture" with European cultures

The example code:

```
string  rawString = "123456789";
// 1. Raw string to raw value (integer) conversion
int    rawInt         = Int32.Parse(rawString);
// 2. Integer to expected double value (given we know we need 2 decimals)
double currencyDouble = rawInt /100.0;
// 3. Expected double value to formated string
string currencyString = currencyDouble.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es"));
Console.WriteLine(currencyString);
// Outputs: 1.234.567,89 €
```

This would be the generic approach:

```
static string IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals(string rawString,  string locale, int decimals) {
    int    rawInt         = Int32.Parse(rawString);
    double currencyDouble = rawInt /Math.Pow(10.0, decimals);
    return currencyDouble.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(locale));
}
```

The generic approach yields:

```
Console.WriteLine(IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals("123456789", "es", 0));
// Outputs: 123.456.789,00 €
Console.WriteLine(IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals("123456789", "es", 2));
// Outputs: 1.234.567,89 €
Console.WriteLine(IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals("123456789", "es", 4));
// Outputs: 12.345,68 €
Console.WriteLine(IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals("123456789", "es", 6));
// Outputs: 123,46 €

Console.WriteLine(IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals("123456789", "fr", 2));
// Outputs: 1 234 567,89 €
Console.WriteLine(IntStringToCurrencyStringWithDecimals("123456789", "de", 2));
// Outputs: 1.234.567,89 €
```