# ASP.NET Core 6: Client-side localized number validation

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, number-formatting, client-side-validation

I use ASP.NET Core 6.0 and want to create an exclusively German-language application. So far everything works fine, not least because of the good content here.

However, I now have a problem that the client-side validation of numbers in German notation ("*1.234.567,89*") simply doesn't work and only the US format ("*1,234,567.89*") is accepted. When entering dates, however, it works fine. I have also been able to successfully implement the German notifications.

The server-side validation also works when the form sends "*1.234.567,89*", this value is also properly recognized, etc. I also added the `<html lang="de-de">` language tag to the main HTML file.

So far I've helped myself by turning off the client-side validation for the relevant fields with  `<input data-val="false" ..... />`.

This code is also stored in Program.cs:

```
var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("de-DE") };
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

Who can help me?

Comment: The German number example seems wrong. Can you check?

Comment: Sorry Corrected now. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Can you show the HTML generated code?

Comment: @vernou: Yes, of course. The code in the source '<input asp-for="nameOfField" class="form-control" />' and the generated code '<input  class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-number="Die Eingabe muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Eingabe erforderlich." name="nameOfField" value="0,00" />'

Comment: Not quite sure what '1.234.567,89' means, so maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119725/how-can-i-convert-123456789-to-1-234-567-89-on-basis-of-currency-symbol-like) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

After I manually downloaded the appropriate jquery validation package, explicitly specified the German validation methods and languages and entered script snippets in the shared validation, it works wonderfully.

```
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation/localization/messages_de.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation/localization/methods_de.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```